# Increment Numbers as String Values in Sheets

Tags: string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, increment, auto-increment

I am trying to increment numbers in Google Sheets as string values so I can use them in IDs, example: "JER_HIL_0000002561".

I know I can drag down the autofill in the corner of the cell, but I am using this for 250,000 records and dragging isn't reasonable.

Is there a quicker way to do this than just dragging the autofiller?

Comment: There seems to be a relevant post on the WebApps Stack Exchange. Does this answer your question? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107133/autofill-large-number-of-cells-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX("JER_HIL_"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(20, 1, 2561), "0000000000"))
```

where you will get 20 ids starting from 2561